# Can I ask this question about unique elments of programming languages?

Tags: discussion

Here's what I'd like to ask:

> What is something that your language does, that is rare or nonexistent in other languages, and often comes in handy in code golfing? Please share a single function, statement, or other construct that is both uncommon in languages broadly and regularly useful for golfing in the language of your choice.

Is that allowed? I've never been quite clear about what sorts of non-competitive questions were appropriate for the site, so I thought I'd check here first. Also, if it is allowed, what do I tag it?

Comment: I think it's best right here, just the way you've done it. Maybe add [tag:faq-request]?  ... ok maybe a little editing down to the *question within the question*. :)

Comment: Oh god please no.

Comment: I thought lists were less not-ok on meta. This goes toward choosing the right language for the task at hand, which is very interesting.

Answer (score 5):

If it's not a challenge, then you should treat it exactly like you would on any other site, except that it should be specifically related to programming puzzles or challenges.

---

I would vote to close your question as Too Broad because it begs for multiple, equally valid but all incomplete answers. This is also known as a "list question". Don't use old tips questions [like this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6671/18487) as a reference. Tips questions are relics - good relics, which is why we don't delete them - created before the community knew what should go where.

Be specific and show some effort on your part to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like the kind of open-ended question which is suitable for the chatroom and nowhere else.